# Selenium 2.0 / webdriver

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am currently looking at choosing a automated web testing framework for use with a current web project. I am pretty sure that I am going to use selenium. I have been reading a little about selenium 2.0 or webdriver. Does webdriver have a recorder plugin like selenium 1.0 or is it just an API for web tests?

I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the direction of some good examples of using it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maintainers of Selenium, sort of answer this question here:
http://www.viddler.com/explore/saucelabs/videos/27/
Look for timestamp 00:56:00  and  00:43:00

Basically, there will probably be IDE support for Selenium 2 eventually.  But it isn't there yet and it's not clear what it will look like.

You should probably be avoiding the IDE anyway. The tests that you record using the IDE tend to be fragile, unmaintainable and hard to read. Once you've learned the basics of Selenium, it's probably better to write your tests in a real programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen - http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html and 
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

Using Selenium IDE we can format recorded code in different languages - Selenium IDE > Option > Format
But did not see any formatter for webdriver, though bumped on to this -

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webdriver-backed-formatters/

Answer (score 0):

Only a few minor adjustments are required to get the existing 1.0 C# scripts running under the 2.0 beta of Selenium.

Check out [this blog post](http://bitbattle.blogspot.com/2011/04/generating-c-scripts-for-selenium-20.html)

Once the RTW release of Selenium is ready, I'm hoping that a better formatter is ready.  Until then, I'm able to use my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium IDE 1.9.x (I am using 1.9.1) or 1.8.x for recording purpose. And then you can export the recording tests into your desired programming language. For example, if you want to convert your recording code (recorded by Selenium IDE) into C# , follow the steps below:

1. Click File menu at Selenium IDE
2. Mouse over "Export Test Case As" and then click "C#/NUnit/WebDriver"
3. Save the file at your desired location

In the same way, you can convert your code to Java, PHP, Ruby etc.

Note: Some code might not be converted exactly in some cases. In that case, it needs to modify code manually